# Android save path and creating files

Tags: android, file

I am trying to save some data for a android game, but I cant create the file.

```
File file = new File(filename);
file.createNewFile();
```

or

```
File file = new File(filename);
file.mkdir();
```

What path should I set? The code above doesn't work. I think I have the read/write correct, but I can't make the file initially (and yes I have googled it)

It is a permanent file for the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a large file, you should create it on external storage (SD card). you can get the path to the ext. Storage by calling [Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29). so,

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "myfile.txt");
```

There is of course no permission on the external storage file system (because it's a FAT file system). If you need the file to be private to your app, you can use [Context.openFileOutput()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput%28java.lang.String,%20int%29),

```
OutputStream os = context.OpenFileOutput("myfile.txt", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

This creates the file in a the app-specific data directory on internal storage. The file is private to the UID of your app, so it cannot be read by other applications.

Comment: Please, do not mix up the two terms / storages: a) the "SD card", which is the internal hardwired storage of the Android device (They use such terminology.); with the b) "external storage", which is also an "SD card", but optional, physical and removable, in the SD/SIM slot nowadays.